# How to select all rows for specific ID only if another column contains specific value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a CSV file that contains hundreds of rows with repeatable IDs. Would there be a way to easily select rows for each ID but only if column customerCount has all the values for corresponding ID = 0?

My CSV file structure:

```
  report_date     id    customerCount    orderNr
  2020-02-20    123        12              10
  2020-02-19    123        18              11
  2020-02-18    123        0               12
  2020-02-20    321        0               0
  2020-02-19    321        0               0
  2020-02-18    321        0               0
  2020-02-20    456        17              13
  2020-02-19    456        0               0
  2020-02-18    456        15              14
  2020-02-20    654        0               0
  2020-02-19    654        0               0
  2020-02-18    654        0               0
  and so on...
```

Desired output CSV:

```
id    customerCount
321         0
654         0
```

My code so far (throws `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('path/to/my/file.csv')
df1 = df.loc[(df.groupby['id'](['customerCount'] == 0)]
df1.to_csv('/path/to/my.output.csv')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First idea is use [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) with mask, then filter mask by itself and convert to `DataFrame`:

```
s = (df['customerCount'] == 0).groupby(df['id']).all()

df = s[s].reset_index()
df['customerCount'] = 0
print (df)
    id  customerCount
0  321              0
1  654              0
```

Or use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with inverted mask by `~` all `id` which no `0` and create `DataFrame` by constructor:

```
ids = df.loc[~df['id'].isin(df.loc[df['customerCount'] != 0, 'id']), 'id'].unique()

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids, 'customerCount':0})
print (df)
    id  customerCount
0  321              0
1  654              0
```

EDIT: Create new `id` values by change mask by remove `~`:

```
mask = df['id'].isin(df.loc[df['customerCount'] != 0, 'id'])
ids1 = df.loc[~mask, 'id'].unique()
ids2 = df.loc[mask, 'id'].unique()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids1, 'customerCount':0})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids2, 'customerCount':'>0'})
print (df1)
    id  customerCount
0  321              0
1  654              0

print (df2)
    id customerCount
0  123            >0
1  456            >0
```

Comment: would you also know how I could get all IDs if they have any of the values bigger than 0 in customerCount column?

Comment: `import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('path/to/my.csv')
s = (df['customerCount'] == 0).groupby(df1['id']).all()

df2 = s[s].reset_index()
df2['customerCount'] = 0

df2.to_csv('path/to/myoutput.csv')

cond = df1['id'].isin(df2['id']) == True
df1.drop(df1[cond].index, inplace = True)
df1.to_csv('my/outputfile.csv')`
The above is not working for me :(

Comment: thank you! So if now I'm doing print(df1) it gives me an empty data frame instead of showing the one that have only 0 in customerCount column. While print(df2) shows correctly IDs for customerCount >0. Would you know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Baobab1988 - It seems my typo, not `ids1 = df.loc[~mask, 'id'].unique().` but `ids1 = df.loc[~mask, 'id'].unique()`

Comment: this is my code:
`import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('my/path/.csv')
mask = df['id'].isin(df.loc[df['customerCount'] != 0, 'id'])
ids1 = df.loc[~mask, 'id'].unique()
ids2 = df.loc[mask, 'id'].unique()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids1, 'customerCount':'0'})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids2, 'customerCount':'>0'})`

Comment: @Baobab1988 - For me working perfect, added output, so no idea.

Comment: silly me... I had df1 = pd.read_csv so that overlapped with df1 which appears later in the code ;-) fixed and thank you again!